# Is it possible to add an image watermark to an image with a condition based on field values of a node?

Tags: media

I am currently using [imagecache_actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) to add an image watermarks to the images I upload.

So far everything is working fine. What I am currently doing is just to simple add the site logo to the bottom right part of the images being uploaded.

Right now, what I am trying to figure out is is it possible for me to be able to add an image watermark to an image with a condition based on field values of a node?

For example, I have an image field in a node let's say it is the a person's image field and then an image watermark that says something like **NEW** if the node is *2 weeks old*. Is that possible? Or maybe if I will add a field in the content type for like **New Member - Yes or No**, and if yes, the New image watermark will be added to the image of the member.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom module and use GD to combine the images using PHP.

Comment: You can also do this in your node template (or in preprocess) to add in logic to render this field differently based upon whatever else is available, node creation date, different field, etc.

Comment: Rules *might* be able to handle this, but I don't know what options are available for the imagecache_actions in rules.